# DFS of a graph using an adjacency matrix (Java)

Tags: java, depth-first-search

Hello I'm having an issue with my code displaying the wrong order when I perform a Depth-First Traversal

```
class graphs{

public static void main(String [] args){
    int[][] adjMatrix = { {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0},
            {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0},
            {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
            {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
            {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
            {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}};
    boolean[] visited = {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false};
    int n = 8;

    DFS(adjMatrix, visited, n, 0);
}

public static void DFS(int[][] adjMatrix, boolean [] visited,int n, int i){
    System.out.print(" " + (i+1));
    visited[i]= true;
    for (int j = 0; j<n;j++){
        if(!(visited[j]) && adjMatrix[i][j]==1){
            DFS(adjMatrix, visited, n, j);
        }

    }
  }
}
```

I was told that I should be getting : 1 2 6 7 4 3 5 8

I, however, keep getting : 1 2 6 5 7 3 4 8

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: It's supposed to display the order visited. Maybe that's where I'm messing up?

Edit: Additionally, how could I have it display the order of the dead ends?

For the dead ends would something like this work:

```
public static void DFS(int[][] adjMatrix, boolean [] visited,int n, int i){
System.out.print(" " + (i+1));
visited[i]= true;
for (int j = 0; j<n;j++){
    if(!(visited[j]) && adjMatrix[i][j]==1){
        DFS(adjMatrix, visited, n, j);
    }

}
a.add(i+1); //assume a is an integer ArrayList and will be printed out later
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were told wrong, your output is correct.

You can check it by hand:

```
       1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
    1 {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}
    2 {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}
    3 {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}
    4 {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
    5 {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}
    6 {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}
    7 {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
    8 {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}
```

You just "jump" until you find a 0, we start at 1, the first 1 in the first row is at column marked 2, we move to row 2, the first 1 in row 2 that was not yet visited/is not being visited currently is at 6, we move to row 6, again the first interesting 1 is at 5, we move to row 5, there are no interesting 1s in that row because we are currently on a path that already visited 1 and 6 so we backtrack, at this point we have 1,2,6,5. We backtrack back to row 2, first interesting 1 is at 7, in row 7 we get 3, at 3 we go to 4, then backtrack to 7 and go to 8 which finishes all nodes with your result.

@Edit: just to make it clear other answers *might* be possible with DFS (depending in which order you will be processing neighbours) but the answer you were supposed to provide is definitely not possible for this input.

@Edit: so to be precise it would be 1 -> 2 -> 6 -> 5 -> backtrack(2) -> 7 -> 3 -> 4 -> 8 -> end

Comment: That is what I thought, but this is an assignment for class and on the assignment it has the that order visited is: 1 2 6 7 4 3 5 8. Is there maybe something I'm missing here?

Comment: No either the input data is incorrect or the person who made the answer simply made a mistake. Notice that there is no 1 in row 6, column 7, that means you would have to backtrack from 6 to 2 to get 7 after 6 *but* you first need to visit all neighbours of 6 to do that (in this case 5).

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been stuck on this for hours.

You wouldn't also happen to be able to explain to me how to have it display the order of the dead ends? I feel like it's something simple that I'm missing.

Comment: dead ends? you mean when you backtrack? you just check if `DFS` was called internally, if not then print `backtrack/dead end`

Comment: I'm supposed to make is display the order that the vertices become dead ends. I was given this for the graph: First dead − ends : 8 7 5 4 1 2 6 3.  Would the best way to do this be adding something after the for loop in the DFS method?

Answer (score 0):

Based in your matrix, adjMatrix[6][5] = 1 but adjMatrix[6][7] = 0, so your expected answer 1 2 6 7 4 3 5 8 is incorrect as there is no link between 6 and 7. You should check input data again, highly chance that you typed in wrongly.

Comment: I double checked. It's exactly as I was given. This is an assignment for class, and it's supposed to display the order visited. Maybe I'm missing something here?